# What else do I need to produce two dots above o?

Tags: accents

In tex file:

```
  Toks\"{o}z
```

It produces

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this case, I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided; it works as expected and produces a proper `ö`.

Comment: Make sure you are using `"` but not strange unicode madness in case you have copied it from a website etc. such as `''`

Comment: It is very obvious I am using " not ' '. At least in my tex file it looks like " to me. I have used "shift" key to input ".

Answer (score 26):

It is difficult to see in some editors, but in the first case you have `\"` acting on `o`, in the second: `\'` acting on `'`, hence the strange result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

 Toks\"{o}z

Toks\''{o}z

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: your question gives an interesting example, why `"` and `''` should never be mixed. Improper usage of `"` as a quote does not give so visible result.

Comment: I use TeXworks as editor. I agree that two separate ' without space between them looks same as ". But I use "shift" key to input ". The result is still same to me.

Comment: @yanfyon TeXworks, by default, auto-converts `"` to `''` (Format -> Smart Quotes). I always turn this off from the Preferences, but some people clearly find it useful. (This happens even if you type in `"` using the standard input method, so you may not be aware of it.)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe that's very naive, but why not simply input direcly `ö` in the editor?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

 Toksöz

\textsc{Toksöz}

 TOKSÖZ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I just found out why this happened. In the TeXworks editor I use, the original setup is: "Format"--> "Smart Quotes"-->"Tex ligatures", after I changed the setup to: "Format"--> "Smart Quotes"-->"None", then it works as expected !!!!

Comment: I am really confused. When I changed the setup of "Smart Quotes" from "None" back to "Tex ligatures" again, it still works normal. But I still believe the abnormal behavior has something to do with the "Smart Quotes" setup.

Comment: I make one more test. If I set the "Smart Quotes" as "Tex ligatures" and re-input Toks\"{o}z, it still comes out as abnormal. So now I am sure the abnormal out is indeed related to the "Smart Quotes" setup.

Comment: The Smart Quotes setting has an effect only at the time you press the `"` key.  Changing Smart Quotes on or off doesn't go through your document and replace existing `"` characters.

Comment: I petition to have this "feature" renamed "dumb quotes". (Especially since all the editor has to do is to check if the previous character is `\ ` and, if so, leave the `"` alone.)