# Cannot write dieresis with *TeXWorks*

Tags: accents, texworks

I am trying to write a dieresis with TexWorks (version 0.4.5 with Windows 8.1, if needed) with the code:

```
\"{a}
```

it should be correct, but this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Probably you've got the 'smart quotes' on, which turns `"` into `''`. Try Format -> Smart Quotes -> None.

Comment: See also e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187716/what-else-do-i-need-to-produce-two-dots-above-o/187733#187733

Comment: @JosephWright Yes that was the problem. Thanks.